# Define a matrix power by some scalars

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials

Suppose I have an nxn matrix, for example:

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}6&-2\\8&-2\end{pmatrix}$$

How is it possible to define the matrix $A^9$ using two scalars $b,c$ in R s.t.:

$A^9 = bA + cI$

I found out that $x^9 = q(x)*p(x)+r(x)$ by dividing the polynom $x^9$ by the characteristic polynomial $p(x)$ 
(Notice that $q(x)$ is the quotient and $r(x)$ is the remainder) .

Then I used the Cayley Hamilton theorem which states that substituting the matrix A for $\lambda$ in the characteristic polynomial, $p(\lambda)$ , satisfies that $p(A)=0$.

I already found out that $2^9 = 2b + c$ but I don't have any idea what to do next.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The characteristic polynomial $\chi_A$ is
$$\chi_A(x)=x^2-\operatorname{tr}(A)x+\det(A)=x^2-4x+4=(x-2)^2$$
so using the Euclidean division we get

$$x^9=q(x)\chi_A(x)+ax+b\tag1$$
Now for $x=2$ we have 
$$2^9=2a+b\tag2$$
and we differentiate  $(1)$ and with $x=2$ we get
$$9\times 2^8=a\tag3$$
Finally solve $(2)$ and $(3)$ for $a$ and $b$ and use the Cayley-Hamilton theorem to get 
$$A^9=aA+bI$$

Comment: It seems very good! Thank you! But one question. Why $9 \times 2^8=a$ ? I don't understand.

Comment: Where did the $9$ came from?

Comment: The derivative of $x^9$ is $9x^8$;